# How to use suitable window function in my case

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am use flink-1.13 sql. I have a kafka table like

```
create my_table(
   id string,
   event_time timestamp(3)
   watermark for time as ...
)
```

I want to group messages every 10 minutes like tumble window, besides I want to recalculate late messages within 1 hour.

One of the way I know is use a udf like

```
select count(1) from my_table
     where event_time >= '1 hour ago'
     group by ten_minutes_udf(event_time)
```

But this way flink state never expired and I can't find a suitable Window TVF Aggregation to do it

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In Flink 1.14 a `current_watermark()` function was added that can be used to detect and operate on late events.

Since before 1.13 there is an experimental `table.exec.emit.allow-lateness` configuration option that can be used with the (now legacy) window operations (and not with window TVFs).